# How to Make Equal Vertical and Horizontal Spacing for Grid of Circles on Google Maps using TypeScript (or JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, geo

I'm currently trying to create a grid of circles overlaying Google Maps in TypeScript or JavaScript. I have a given center point for this grid, along with specific parameters for grid size and spacing between circles.

My aim is to create a function that can accurately calculate and output the coordinates for this grid of circles.

While my current implementation almost achieves this, there's an issue with the spacing between circles - the vertical spacing between circles is larger than the horizontal spacing. This isn't the intended result, I need the grid to have equal spacing horizontally and vertically.

Below is the code I have written so far:

```TypeScript
const center = { lat: 39.9511163, lng: -75.1651992 };
const gridSize = 7;
const spacing = 0.002;

const createGrid = (
  center: google.maps.LatLngLiteral,
  gridSize: number,
  spacing: number
) => {
  const grid = [];
  const start = Math.floor(gridSize / 2);
  for (let i = -start; i <= start; i++) {
    for (let j = -start; j <= start; j++) {
      grid.push({
        lat: center.lat + i * spacing,
        lng: center.lng + j * spacing,
      });
    }
  }
  return grid;
};

const circles = createGrid(center, gridSize, spacing);
```

The resulting grid from this code isn't quite right. Here's an image to illustrate what I mean:

[image]

Can anyone guide me on how to adjust the code so that the coordinates of the grid have equal vertical and horizontal distances between each circle?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that earth is not a perfect sphere, so locations further away from the equator are distorted when dealing with lat and long.

So I changed to using turf.js which accounts for that.

```
const createGrid = (
  centerPosition: google.maps.LatLngLiteral,
  gridPointsPerSide: number,
  gridSizePerSide: number,
  gridSizeUnits: Units
) => {
  // Calculate the cell size
  const cellSize = gridSizePerSide / (gridPointsPerSide - 1);

  // Calculate half the grid size to find the distance from center to edges of bounding box
  const halfGridSize = gridSizePerSide / 2;

  // Make the bounding box
  // Extend it by 10% of a cell (cellSize / 10) to include grid cells on
  // the east and north edges when gridSizePerSide is an exact multiple of the grid spacing
  const boundingBox = bbox(
    buffer(
      point([centerPosition.lng, centerPosition.lat]),
      halfGridSize + cellSize / 10,
      {
        units: gridSizeUnits,
      }
    )
  );

  // Make the grid
  const grid = pointGrid(boundingBox, cellSize, {
    units: gridSizeUnits,
  });

  // Extract coordinates
  const coordinates = grid.features.map((feature) => {
    const [longitude, latitude] = feature.geometry.coordinates;
    return { latitude, longitude };
  });

  return coordinates;
};
```

Comment: well it be fair, the earth is a perfect sphere. but having a spacingLat that is different from your spacingLng would probably solve the issue as well.

Comment: @Rick Actually the Earth is an [irregularly shaped ellipsoid](https://oceanservice.noaa.gov/facts/earth-round.html#:~:text=The%20Earth%20is%20an%20irregularly%20shaped%20ellipsoid.&text=While%20the%20Earth%20appears%20to,actually%20closer%20to%20an%20ellipsoid.). Not sure if that was the exact cause or not, but using turf.js solved the problem and made other tasks easier also so I kept it.